# page reloading prevents invoking nested ajax callback method

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Background: I have the following code in javascript, which has a nested ajax callbacks method.
I noticed if I added page reload using "window.location.reload();" before the second
callback method, then although the second request would be sent to the server, the 
callback method would not be invoked.

Question: **Could anybody explain me the reason behind? (Why the page reload/refresh does not block the subsequent request being sent, but prevents the subsequent callback method from being invoked?)**

Sample code as follows:

```
function sync(accountId, type, sagId) {
        var url = "some url" 
        var name = "";
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "GET",
            username: $('#login_username').val(),
            password: $('#login_password').val(),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function(result) {

                window.location.reload(); // this is the line causes issue. 


                if (confirm(message)) {
                    // Save it!
                    var url = "another url"

                    $.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        type: "GET",
                        username: $('#login_username').val(),
                        password: $('#login_password').val(),
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        success: function(result) {
                            // if the line "window.location.reload();" was uncommentted, I found this call back function will NOT be invoked. (i.e. it would not reach here anyways for some reason, although the request to the second url (in this case the GET request to the "another url" would still be made.)

                            if (result === "OK") {
                                alert("Successfully");
                            } else {
                                alert(result);
                            }
                        },
                        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                            var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                            console.log(err);
                            alert(err);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    alert("Sync cancelled.");
                    return;
                }


            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                alert("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                return;
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.reload(); // this is the line causes issue.`

is the same as page refresh, so either remove it or, move to a location where you want that to happen.

perhaps in the second ajax success... is a better spot

Comment: thanks, you are right. I want to understand why page refresh causes the second callback not being invoked?

Comment: because it never get there.... as soon as window.location.reload();... it start refreshing the page..... like as if you click in the url... and hit enter or f5, it stops doing what it was... as the page... aka the js and everything no longer exits... and the new js is loaded, which will be the same.... but as if loaded for the first time as it is just that loaded fresh..

Comment: it makes sense, but then i can figure out how come it (page reloading) does not impact the second request being sent?

Comment: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-deal-with-asynchronous-code-in-javascript-e9f437b46832 that link will tell you... i didnt want to get the wording incorrect.... but js by default ... does not block... there a better way to say this.. i just dont want to get the wording incorrect.... its something like `javascript is always asynchronous unless made to act synchronously`.. im sure someone will correct me.. if im wrong with the wording.